# How to apply the learned model in Matlab after cross-validation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

Once the classifier is trained and tested using cross-validation approach, how does one use the results to validate on an unseen data especially during free running stage / deployment stage? How does one use the learned model? the following code trains and tests the data `X` using cross-validation. How am I supposed to use the learned model after the line `pred = predict(svmModel, X(istest,:));` is computed?

```
part = cvpartition(Y,'Holdout',0.5);
istrain = training(part); % Data for fitting
istest = test(part);      % Data for quality assessment
balance_Train=tabulate(Y(istrain))
NumbTrain = sum(istrain);         % Number of observations in the training sample
NumbTest = sum(istest);
svmModel = fitcsvm(X(istrain,:),Y(istrain), 'KernelFunction','rbf');
pred = predict(svmModel, X(istest,:));
% compute the confusion matrix
cmat = confusionmat(Y(istest),pred);
acc = 100*sum(diag(cmat))./sum(cmat(:))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [clue's in the name](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm.predict.html):

> **predict**
>
> Predict labels using support vector machine (SVM) classifier
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `label = predict(SVMModel,X)`
>
> `[label,score] = predict(SVMModel,X)`
>
> **Description**
>
> `label = predict(SVMModel,X)` returns a vector of predicted class labels
>   for the predictor data in the table or matrix X, based on the trained
>   support vector machine (SVM) classification model SVMModel. The
>   trained SVM model can either be full or compact.

In the code in your question, the code from `pred = ...` onwards is there to evaluate the predictions made by your `svmModel` object. However you can take the same object and use it to make predictions with further input dataset(s) - or, better, train a second model using *all* the data, and use that model for making actual predictions on new, unknown inputs.

You seem to be unclear on the role of (cross-)validation in model building. You should **build your deployment model using the whole dataset** (`X`, as per your comment), because as a rule more data always gives you a better model. To *estimate how good this deployment model will be*, you build one or more models from subsets of X and test each model against the rest of X that wasn't in that model's training subset. If you only do this once, this is called holdout validation; if you use multiple subsets and average the outcomes it's cross-validation.

If it's important to you for some reason that the deployed model is exactly the same one that you used to obtain your validation results, then you can deploy the model that was trained on the training partition of your holdout. But as I said, more training data usually results in a better model.